# Open hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

can anyone help me making my "hamburger menu" do something? I want that, when a person clicks on it, words like "Home and Works" appear on the side. And then when you close it, and goes to its previous form, the menu disappears as well.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
  <div class="bar4"></div>
  <div class="bar6"></div>
  <div class="bar5"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  z-index: 99
}


.bar1{
  width: 48px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.bar2{
  width: 48px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.bar3{
  width: 48px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(134, 134, 134);
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.bar4{
  width: 48px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


.bar5{
  width: 20px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
  z-index: 99
}

.bar6 {
  width: 37.5px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
  z-index: 99
}

.bar7 {
  width: 37.5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
  z-index: 99
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
transform: rotate(-75deg) translate(-22px, 18px) ;
}

/* Rotate second bar */
.change .bar2 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
transform: rotate(75deg) translate(15px, 1.5px) ;
}

/* Rotate third bar */
.change .bar3 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
transform: rotate(-75deg) translate(-3.5px,3px) ;
}

/* Rotate forth bar */
.change .bar4 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
transform: rotate(75deg) translate(-2.9px, -14px) ;
}

/* Rotate fifth bar */
.change .bar6 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0px, -12.7px) ;
}

/* Rotate sixth bar */
.change .bar5 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(54px, 21.5px) ;
}


</style>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>
```

What do I need to put more? Those bars function as my logo, so I didn't want to get them off, but at the same time, as a newbie, I don't know how to incorporate a menu in it.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello Igor, I'm a little confused as to what you need?! What's the CSS for `bar 7` supposed to be doing? Also your question talks about adding words to the page, but it looks like the code is trying to make the bars rotate?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. What I am searching for is that, whenever you go to those bars and click on them, they will rotate and form a logo; as this process occurs, a menu is also open with "Home", "Works" and "About Me" on the side. I don't know how to put the code to do those things at the same time. 

The - bar 7 - is a mistake, sorry.